# TensorFlow - How to Get My Loss Value from tf.Estimaor

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to train an alexnet model using tf.estimator in TensorFlow. The training process works smoothly, and I can see the logs well displayed.

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 2.61362, step = 294
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 325 into /home/olu/Dev/data_base
sign_base/output/Checkpoints_N_Model/trained_alexnet_model/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 2.94104.
```

Below is how the training function is called:

```
traffic_sign_classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,hooks=[logging_hook])
```

Please, how can I get my loss value as a normal python floating point from the tf estimator object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .evaluate() method on the estimator returns a dictionary of metrics you can specify in your model function, in the estimator spec, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec eval_metric_ops. I found the answer on this thread on GitHub [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12093)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain what was the solution? Giving raw links is generally bad habit on SO

Answer (score 3):

You can download the loss values from tensorboard when finishing your training.

[image]

Comment: @secslim I actually need to get it in real time as the training is in progress. Thats what I'm trying to do

Comment: Basically, how can I evaluate 
    tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, 
    eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops) 

and get the values stored in it